# Preg Replace para retirar font awesome dos textos

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Estou precisando montar um `preg_replace` do PHP para retirar todos **font-awesome** de uma string. por ex.:

```
Texto de teste <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i> Teste Lorem Ipsim
```

Teria que mudar para

```
Texto de teste Teste Lorem Ipsim
```

Já tentei varias expressões regulares mas sou uma negação nisso ainda não entendi o funcionamento básico. Se alguém puder me explicar como se montar esta regex eu ficaria muito agradecido.

Comment: Vc quer remover do documento ainda no server-side, ou quer apenas que não fique visível na tela?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez seja mais fácil usar um *parser* de HTML, como o [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), por exemplo:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html); // $html é uma string contendo o HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//i[contains(@class, 'fa-')]") as $i) { // procura elementos i com classe fa-*
    $i->parentNode->removeChild($i);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

No caso, eu procuro por elementos `i` que contém uma classe cujo nome começa com `fa-`, e removo-os do HTML.

---

Com regex é um pouco mais complicado, mas podemos assumir que a tag `i` sempre está nesse formato (`<i class="classes"></i>`): sem nenhum conteúdo entre a abertura e fechamento da tag, e sempre com os nomes das classes no atributo `class` (e nenhum outro atributo). Então a regex poderia ser algo do tipo:

```
$str = 'Texto de teste <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i> Teste Lorem Ipsim <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i> abc etc';
echo preg_replace('/<i class="[^"]*\bfa-[^"]*"><\/i>/', '', $str);
```

Eu uso uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) (`[^"]`), que significa qualquer coisa que **não** seja `"`. Assim, eu verifico se dentro das aspas existe uma classe cujo nome seja `fa-(qualquer-coisa)`.

Eu uso o atalho `\b` ([*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) para garantir que antes do `f` não exista nenhum caractere alfanumérico, evitando assim falsos-positivos (como por exemplo um nome que fosse `alfa-alguma-coisa`).

O resultado é que as tags `i` são removidas:

```
Texto de teste  Teste Lorem Ipsim  abc etc
```

Mas repare que os espaços antes e depois da tag não são removidos (se bem que isso [não fará diferença no HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17784595)). Mas se quiser muito removê-los, pode mudar para:

```
preg_replace('/ *<i class="[^"]*\bfa-[^"]*"><\/i>/', '', $str);
```

Repare que agora, antes do `<i` há um espaço seguido do [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Assim, os espaços antes da tag `i` também são removidos.

Se você só tem esses casos mais simples, esta regex já deve ser o suficiente. Se tiver casos mais complicados, aí provavelmente será melhor usar `DOMDocument` mesmo. [Regex não é a melhor ferramenta para trabalhar com HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Answer (score 1):

O problema em usar o `DOMDocument()` é que ele adiciona "lixo" no resultado. Por exemplo, ao remover a tag da string:

```
$string = 'Texto de teste <i class="fab fa-accusoft">xxx</i> Teste Lorem Ipsim <i class="fab fa-accusoft">xxx</i>';
```

O resultado será:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Texto de teste  Teste Lorem Ipsim </p></body></html>
```

Ele até remove a tag que você quer, mas repare que ele acrescenta as tags `DOCTYPE`, `html`, `body`, e `p`.

Para resolver isso, você teria que usar outras funções para remover todo o lixo e retornar apenas a string sem as tags do fontawesome.

Você terá que remover espaços duplos deixado pelo "buraco" onde estava a tag do fontawesome, remover possíveis espaços no final ou início da string e remover as outras tags citadas acima.

Para isso, use os parâmetros `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` no `loadHTML` e o resto você remove com replaces e `trim()`:

```
<?
$string = 'Texto de teste <i class="fab fa-accusoft">xxx</i> Teste Lorem Ipsim <i class="fab fa-accusoft">xxx</i>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($selector->query('//i[contains(attribute::class, "fa-")]') as $e){
    $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
}

$string = trim(preg_replace('/<p>|<\/p>/', '', str_replace('  ', ' ', $doc->saveHTML())));

echo $string;
?>
```

**[Veja no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/1DNTTI)**

Sem os tratamentos que citei acima, veja o resultado como fica:

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/SpNoM6)**

Comment: Eu até pensei em escrever sobre isso, mas fiquei na dúvida se ele tem o HTML inteiro e o texto da pergunta é só um trecho de exemplo. De qualquer forma, +1 :-)